# Smart UV Project Island Margins do nothing

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

I'm unwrapping the whole scene using `Smart UV Project` and I want all UV islands to be slightly separated, but no matter what `Island Margin` value I choose, all island are tightly packed to each other. I'm observing this behavior in `Edit Mode` with `Draw Other Objects` option on.

What's wrong here?

Comment: Try set island margin to 0.001.